# Call HTML Divs from External HTML Doc

Tags: html, call, external

So this is what I want to do…

I have a single HTML page as a website, and there is a certain section halfway down (inside a div) that my client wants to be able to access and change/add wording occasionally. I don't want to give him access to the whole HTML page because he will potentially break it.

So what I want to do is set up a separate HTML document - with a simple set of divs easy enough for him to change - with the information, and then from within the main HTML document call this external set of divs into the page (at that specific section). Can't for the life of me figure out how to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). From the documentation:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `iframe` in the particular `div`, pass the external `html page` as `iframe source`

HTML:

```
<div>
<iframe src="external.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

- The HTML  Element (or HTML inline frame element) represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page.
- Advantage of iframe is that you can load only the iframe content ,without having to refresh/load the main html again.